# Why superclass invokes the subclass's overridden method?

Tags: java

I have two classes, Parent (superclass) and Child (subclass).

```
public class Parent(){

   public void hello(){
       System.out.println("HelloParent");
       bye();
   }

   public void bye(){
       System.out.println("ByeParent");
   }
}

public class Child extends Parent(){

   @Override
   public void hello(){
       super.hello();
   }

   @Override
   public void bye(){
       System.out.println("ByeChild");
   }
}
```

If I create a `Child` instance and invoke its `hello()` method, it invokes the `Child`'s `hello` method, and not the `Parent`'s `hello` method.

```
Child c = new Child();
c.hello();
```

Output:

```
"HelloParent"
"ByeChild"
```

But why is it not "ByeParent"?

Why doesn't it invoke the superclass's method?

Comment: Think of it like this: It's borrowing its parent's method, not becoming a parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is how polymorphism works in OO. Since the instance you are working with is `Child`, it is no surprise that `Child.bye()` was invoked!

If you really wanted it to print `ByeParent`, then you'd have to write the `bye()` in `Child` as follows:

```
@Override
public void bye(){
    super.bye();
    System.out.println("ByeChild");
}
```

Note that you could've also done this:

```
Parent obj = new Child();
obj.hello();
```

However, even in this case, it would still print `ByeChild`.

Answer (score 2):

Any instance method call will happen on the object the instance belong to no matter where the code is. So while executing this code:

```
 public void hello(){
       System.out.println("HelloParent");
       bye();
   }
```

`bye` method will be called on the the calling object i.e. `Child` and hence Child method is called.

Comment: Okay, it is a very good exaple, now I understand it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Overriding a method replaces it completely, it doesn't add on to it. If you also want to call the original method, you need to call it explicitly using the keyword "super":

```
@Override
public void bye(){
    super.bye();
    System.out.println("ByeChild");
}
```